# Android Studio not installing properly

Tags: android, android-studio

I have downloaded Android Studio bundle on my Windows 7 PC.The problem is that I am unable to setup the Android Studio.Every time when I install the Android Studio and start a project then I get some junit error message.Being a newbie I am really frustrated because of Android Studio.Can we use Eclipse or has Google stopped supporting it?

Comment: idk we can start with you showing us what errors you got.

Comment: can u post the complete error message which you are getting or post the snapshot of that?

Comment: ^this and wild guess: remove the junit dependency from your gradle file

Comment: whats your error??

Comment: Hello friends,I am getting this error " Failed to resolve : Error:(23, 17) junit:junit:4.12".

Comment: Sorry for bothering you guys but I have uninstalled Android Studio and deleted all the associated folders and I have downloaded the Android Studio bundle again.Now,I want to ask you that is internet connectivity necessary for successful installation because somehow my wifi network is not working properly.Can I install Android studio without Internet connectivity.

Answer (score 2):

Now The Official IDE for Android is Android Studio. Try using Studio, you will learn it.

In your Project, Go to `app` folder, then open `build.gradle` file, under

`dependencies{`

delete this line `testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'`.

Now sync project with gradle. Then build and Run, your project.

---

### Another solution

You can download Junit from here https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/releases

and put it under D:\YourWorkSpace\MyApplication\app\libs folder.
Then go to File > Project Structure

**Project Structure window**

under **Modules**-- app >> Dependencies, Select (+) > 2. File dependency > 
under Select path window,

expand the '**libs**' folder, Select the Jar file you copied here. 
click 'OK'.

Now remove(-) the previous version of junit4.12 by selecting it from the list of dependencies.
Press 'OK'.

This will create entry in your build.gradle file under app folder like this

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile files('libs/junit-4.12.jar')
}
```

Now, Sync this gradle file first and buld and Run your code.

Whenever you edit build.gradle file you need to Sync it first.

Sync button is like circle with arrow pointed downwards from center of the Circle, present in Toolbar. 
After that perform build and Run your project.

Comment: What do you have against Junit? The repositories section could be edited so the dependency is resolved

Comment: Hello friends,I am getting this error " Failed to resolve : Error:(23, 17) junit:junit:4.12".

Comment: I have nothing against Junit, just a easy solution. As he is new to android and i don't want him to stuck in this.